# Trying to implement a simple java program using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class ThreadLogic implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private int time;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public ThreadLogic(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = rand.nextInt(1000);


    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.printf("%s is sleeping for %d \n", this.name, this.time);
            Thread.sleep(this.time);
             System.out.printf("%s is done.\n", this.name);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadLogic("Thread-1"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadLogic("Thread-2"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadLogic("Thread-3"));

       t1.start();
       //t1.stop();
       t2.start();
       t3.start();
       t1.stop();
       System.out.println("State of Thread-1:"+" "+t1.getState());
       System.out.println("State of Thread-2"+" "+t2.getState());
       System.out.println("State of Thread-3"+"  "+t3.getState());
       System.out.println("isalive:"+t1.isAlive());
       System.out.println("isalive:"+t2.isAlive());
       System.out.println("isalive:"+t3.isAlive()); 

       }
    }
```

From the above code, how can I implement such logic in `run()` method: if the thread is waiting for more than the specified time I want to kill that thread and check what happens to the other two threads that are running. When I execute the above code it gives the following output.

> State of Thread-1: TERMINATED
>   
> State of Thread-2 RUNNABLE
>   
> State of Thread-3  RUNNABLE
>   
> isalive:false
>   
> isalive:true
>   
> isalive:true
>   
> Thread-2 is sleeping for 151 
>   
> Thread-3 is sleeping for 384 
>   
> Thread-2 is done.
>   
> Thread-3 is done.

Answer (score 0):

First `thread.stop()` should **not** be used as it is deprecated. (*Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) why*)

Secondly consider using [ExecutorService.submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) to execute a thread; which will return a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). On this `future` object you can either directly invoke [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) after manually waiting for desired time limit *OR* invoke [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) which take the time to wait before terminating with a `TimeoutException` after interval expires, post which you could cancel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.can you explain me through the program it would be great i am not so good at programming this was an assignment to me.I have submit it real quick.This is my learning stage..................